# Mailcore2 [Gmail]

Tags: ios, mailcore2

When I want to get all message from gmail folders (INBOX worked) I have error like: "The requested folder does not exist.  Folder selection failed"

In others mail's worked fine this code but gmail not work(

```
_mailSession = [MailWorkerIMAP getIMAPSession];

[[_mailSession fetchAllFoldersOperation] start:^(NSError *error, NSArray *folders) {
    [[AllMailFolders sharedInstance].folderList removeAllObjects];
    for (MCOIMAPFolder *fdr in folders) {
        NSArray * sections = [fdr.path componentsSeparatedByString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",fdr.delimiter]];
        NSString *folderName = [sections lastObject];
        const char *stringAsChar = [folderName cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
        folderName = [NSString stringWithCString:stringAsChar encoding:CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingUTF7_IMAP)];
        [folderList addObject:folderName];
         NSLog (@"folder: %@",folderName);
    }
}];
```

result:

```
folder: INBOX
folder: [Gmail]
folder: Важное
folder: Вся почта
folder: Корзина
folder: Отправленные
folder: Помеченные
folder: Спам
folder: Черновики
```

when I want to fetch messages:

```
MCOIMAPSession *session = [MailWorkerIMAP getIMAPSession];
if (!session) return;

MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind requestKind = MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders;
MCOIndexSet *uids = [MCOIndexSet indexSetWithRange:MCORangeMake(1, UINT64_MAX)];

MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation *fetchOperation = [session fetchMessagesOperationWithFolder:folder requestKind:requestKind uids:uids];
    [fetchOperation start:^(NSError * error, NSArray * fetchedMessages, MCOIndexSet * vanishedMessages) {
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"Error downloading message headers:%@", error);
            if (requestResult) requestResult(NO);
        }
```

Folder INBOX work fine, but other folder gives error like:

```
folder 1 Важное
Error downloading message headers:Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=11 "The requested folder does not exist.  Folder selection failed" UserInfo=0x7b173580 {NSLocalizedDescription=The requested folder does not exist.  Folder selection failed}
```

and all the rest folders has same error

Comment: Have you tried `[folderList addObject:fdr.path];` instead?

Comment: So, have you solve this error now?